# Having problems with connect 4 and tkinter

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I'm trying to code a connect 4 game using tkinter where the computer makes random moves. I'm very new to python so my code is massively inefficient and clunky. My main problem is when the user clicks on a column to place a piece in it the tkinter window crashes. This seems to be caused by the second while loop but without it the program doesn't wait for the user to choose a column before making a computer move. Here's my code:

```
    import random
from tkinter import *


def setUpStacks():
    return [[],[],[],[],[],[],[]]

def getStack(prompt,allStacks):
    validInput=False
    while validInput==False:
        stack=int(input(prompt))-1
        if len(allStacks[stack])<6:
            if stack in range(7):
                validInput=True
            else:
                print('Please enter a value from 1 to 7.')
        else:
            print('That stack is full.')
    return stack

def putInStack(stack,allStacks,player):
    allStacks[stack]+=[player]
    return allStacks

def changePlayer(player):
    if player=='red':
        player='blue'
    elif player=='blue':
        player='red'
    return player

def checkForWin(stack,allStacks):
    play=True
    pos=len(allStacks[stack])-1
    if len(allStacks[stack])>3:
        if allStacks[stack][-1]==allStacks[stack][-2]==allStacks[stack][-3]==allStacks[stack][-4]:
            play=False
    if stack>2: ##XXXO
        if len(allStacks[stack-1])>=pos+1 and len(allStacks[stack-2])>=pos+1 and len(allStacks[stack-3])>=pos+1:
            if diagonalCheck(0,-1,pos,stack,allStacks)==False:
                play=False
        if len(allStacks[stack-1])>=pos+2 and len(allStacks[stack-2])>=pos+3 and len(allStacks[stack-3])>=pos+4:
            if diagonalCheck(1,-1,pos,stack,allStacks)==False:
                play=False
        if 2<len(allStacks[stack-1])>=pos and 1<len(allStacks[stack-2])>=pos-1 and 0<len(allStacks[stack-3])>=pos-2:
            if diagonalCheck(-1,-1,pos,stack,allStacks)==False:
                play=False
    if 1<stack<6: ##XXOX
        if len(allStacks[stack-1])>=pos+1 and len(allStacks[stack-2])>=pos+1 and len(allStacks[stack+1])>=pos+1:
            if middleCheck(0,-1,pos,stack,allStacks)==False:
                play=False
        if len(allStacks[stack-1])>=pos+2 and len(allStacks[stack-2])>=pos+3 and 1<=len(allStacks[stack+1])>=pos:
            if middleCheck(1,-1,pos,stack,allStacks)==False:
                play=False
        if 2<=len(allStacks[stack-1])>=pos and 1<=len(allStacks[stack-2])>=pos-1 and 4<=len(allStacks[stack+1])>=pos+2:
            if middleCheck(-1,-1,pos,stack,allStacks)==False:
                play=False
    if stack<4: ##OXXX
        if len(allStacks[stack+1])>=pos+1 and len(allStacks[stack+2])>=pos+1 and len(allStacks[stack+3])>=pos+1:
            if diagonalCheck(0,1,pos,stack,allStacks)==False:
                play=False
        if len(allStacks[stack+1])>=pos+2 and len(allStacks[stack+2])>=pos+3 and len(allStacks[stack+3])>=pos+4:
            if diagonalCheck(1,1,pos,stack,allStacks)==False:
                play=False
        if 2<len(allStacks[stack+1])>=pos and 1<len(allStacks[stack+2])>=pos-1 and 0<len(allStacks[stack+3])>=pos-2:
            if diagonalCheck(-1,1,pos,stack,allStacks)==False:
                play=False
    if 0<stack<5: ##XOXX
        if len(allStacks[stack+1])>=pos+1 and len(allStacks[stack+2])>=pos+1 and len(allStacks[stack-1])>=pos+1:
            if middleCheck(0,1,pos,stack,allStacks)==False:
                play=False
        if len(allStacks[stack+1])>=pos+2 and len(allStacks[stack+2])>=pos+3 and len(allStacks[stack-1])>=pos:
            if middleCheck(1,1,pos,stack,allStacks)==False:
                play=False
        if 2<=len(allStacks[stack+1])>=pos and 1<=len(allStacks[stack+2])>=pos-1 and 4<=len(allStacks[stack-1])>=pos+1:
            if middleCheck(-1,1,pos,stack,allStacks)==False:
                play=False
    return play

def diagonalCheck(dirUp,dirAcross,pos,stack,allStacks):
    if allStacks[stack][pos]==allStacks[stack+dirAcross][pos+dirUp]==allStacks[stack+(2*dirAcross)][pos+(2*dirUp)]==allStacks[stack+(3*dirAcross)][pos+(3*dirUp)]:
        return False
    else:
        return True

def middleCheck(dirUp,dirAcross,pos,stack,allStacks):
    if allStacks[stack][pos]==allStacks[stack-dirAcross][pos-dirUp]==allStacks[stack+dirAcross][pos+dirUp]==allStacks[stack+(2*dirAcross)][pos+(2*dirUp)]:
        return False
    else:
        return True

def compMove():
    return random.randint(0,6)

def c1Click(click):
    global num
    num=0
def c2Click(click):
    global num
    num=1
def c3Click(click):
    global num
    num=2
def c4Click(click):
    global num
    num=3
def c5Click(click):
    global num
    num=4
def c6Click(click):
    global num
    num=5
def c7Click(click):
    global num
    num=6

window=Tk()
window.title("Connect 4")
c1=Canvas(window,width=100,height=600,background='gray')
c2=Canvas(window,width=100,height=600,background='gray')
c3=Canvas(window,width=100,height=600,background='gray')
c4=Canvas(window,width=100,height=600,background='gray')
c5=Canvas(window,width=100,height=600,background='gray')
c6=Canvas(window,width=100,height=600,background='gray')
c7=Canvas(window,width=100,height=600,background='gray')

circ11=c1.create_oval(0,500,100,600,fill="white")
circ12=c1.create_oval(0,400,100,500,fill="white")
circ13=c1.create_oval(0,300,100,400,fill="white")
circ14=c1.create_oval(0,200,100,300,fill="white")
circ15=c1.create_oval(0,100,100,200,fill="white")
circ16=c1.create_oval(0,0,100,100,fill="white")

circ21=c2.create_oval(0,500,100,600,fill="white")
circ22=c2.create_oval(0,400,100,500,fill="white")
circ23=c2.create_oval(0,300,100,400,fill="white")
circ24=c2.create_oval(0,200,100,300,fill="white")
circ25=c2.create_oval(0,100,100,200,fill="white")
circ26=c2.create_oval(0,0,100,100,fill="white")

circ31=c3.create_oval(0,500,100,600,fill="white")
circ32=c3.create_oval(0,400,100,500,fill="white")
circ33=c3.create_oval(0,300,100,400,fill="white")
circ34=c3.create_oval(0,200,100,300,fill="white")
circ35=c3.create_oval(0,100,100,200,fill="white")
circ36=c3.create_oval(0,0,100,100,fill="white")

circ41=c4.create_oval(0,500,100,600,fill="white")
circ42=c4.create_oval(0,400,100,500,fill="white")
circ43=c4.create_oval(0,300,100,400,fill="white")
circ44=c4.create_oval(0,200,100,300,fill="white")
circ45=c4.create_oval(0,100,100,200,fill="white")
circ46=c4.create_oval(0,0,100,100,fill="white")

circ51=c5.create_oval(0,500,100,600,fill="white")
circ52=c5.create_oval(0,400,100,500,fill="white")
circ53=c5.create_oval(0,300,100,400,fill="white")
circ54=c5.create_oval(0,200,100,300,fill="white")
circ55=c5.create_oval(0,100,100,200,fill="white")
circ56=c5.create_oval(0,0,100,100,fill="white")

circ61=c6.create_oval(0,500,100,600,fill="white")
circ62=c6.create_oval(0,400,100,500,fill="white")
circ63=c6.create_oval(0,300,100,400,fill="white")
circ64=c6.create_oval(0,200,100,300,fill="white")
circ65=c6.create_oval(0,100,100,200,fill="white")
circ66=c6.create_oval(0,0,100,100,fill="white")

circ71=c7.create_oval(0,500,100,600,fill="white")
circ72=c7.create_oval(0,400,100,500,fill="white")
circ73=c7.create_oval(0,300,100,400,fill="white")
circ74=c7.create_oval(0,200,100,300,fill="white")
circ75=c7.create_oval(0,100,100,200,fill="white")
circ76=c7.create_oval(0,0,100,100,fill="white")

circs=[[circ11,circ12,circ13,circ14,circ15,circ16],[circ21,circ22,circ23,circ24,circ25,circ26],[circ31,circ32,circ33,circ34,circ35,circ36],[circ41,circ42,circ43,circ44,circ45,circ46],[circ51,circ52,circ53,circ54,circ55,circ56],[circ61,circ62,circ63,circ64,circ65,circ66],[circ71,circ72,circ73,circ74,circ75,circ76]]
bottomCirc=[0,0,0,0,0,0,0]

c1.grid(row=1,column=1)
c2.grid(row=1,column=2)
c3.grid(row=1,column=3)
c4.grid(row=1,column=4)
c5.grid(row=1,column=5)
c6.grid(row=1,column=6)
c7.grid(row=1,column=7)

c1.bind("<Button-1>",c1Click)
c2.bind("<Button-1>",c2Click)
c3.bind("<Button-1>",c3Click)
c4.bind("<Button-1>",c4Click)
c5.bind("<Button-1>",c5Click)
c6.bind("<Button-1>",c6Click)
c7.bind("<Button-1>",c7Click)

play=True
player='red'
stacks=setUpStacks()
num=8
chooseStack=num
while play==True:
    player=changePlayer(player)
    while chooseStack==8:
        window.update_idletasks()
        window.update()
        if player=="blue":
            chooseStack=num
        else:
            chooseStack=compMove()
    if chooseStack==0:
        if bottomCirc[0]<6:
            c1.itemconfig(circs[0][(bottomCirc[0])], fill=player)
            bottomCirc[0]+=1
    if chooseStack==1:
        if bottomCirc[1]<6:
            c2.itemconfig(circs[1][(bottomCirc[1])], fill=player)
            bottomCirc[1]+=1
    if chooseStack==2:
        if bottomCirc[2]<6:
            c3.itemconfig(circs[2][(bottomCirc[2])], fill=player)
            bottomCirc[2]+=1
    if chooseStack==3:
        if bottomCirc[3]<6:
            c4.itemconfig(circs[3][(bottomCirc[3])], fill=player)
            bottomCirc[3]+=1
    if chooseStack==4:
        if bottomCirc[4]<6:
            c5.itemconfig(circs[4][(bottomCirc[4])], fill=player)
            bottomCirc[4]+=1
    if chooseStack==5:
        if bottomCirc[5]<6:
            c6.itemconfig(circs[5][(bottomCirc[5])], fill=player)
            bottomCirc[5]+=1
    if chooseStack==6:
        if bottomCirc[6]<6:
            c7.itemconfig(circs[6][(bottomCirc[6])], fill=player)
            bottomCirc[6]+=1
    print(chooseStack)
    num=8
##    stacks=putInStack(chooseStack,stacks,player)
##    play=checkForWin(chooseStack,stacks)
```

Like I said, I'm very new to python so I'm working from limited knowledge but I'm hoping you can understand and help me :)

Comment: are you able to provide the error stack? and maybe provide a minimalist code sample which relates to your problem (which you should be able to pinpoint from your error stack)?

Comment: Don't use `while` loops. You should use `c1Click`, `c2Click`, etc. to do all the job. And use for-loop to create canvases and other elements - use lists to keep elements - `canvases[0]` instead of `c1` - and  then you can use `for`-loops to make code shorter.

Comment: and use spaces after `,` and around `=` to make code more readable - [PEP 8 -- Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't use `while`-loops. You can do everything without this loops - inside `c1Click`, `c2Click`, etc.

It is example how to use button click to do it. It shows also how to use `for`-loops and lists to make code shorter.

Code is not finished but it already draws board and change circles color for human and computer.

```
import random
import tkinter as tk

def make_move(player, choose_stack):
    print('[DEBUG] make_move:', player, choose_stack)

    if bottom_circles[choose_stack] >= 6:
        return False # can't make move

    col = choose_stack
    row = bottom_circles[col]
    circle = circles[col][row]
    print('[DEBUG] col/row/circles:', col, row, circle)

    canvases[col].itemconfig(circle, fill=player)
    bottom_circles[col] += 1

    return True # move was OK

def on_click(event, number):
    global player

    # --- human ---

    player = 'red'

    choose_stack = number

    if not make_move(player, choose_stack):
        print("Wrong move - full stack")
        return # skip computer move

    # TODO: check if human wins

    #if sum(bottom_circles) == 7*6:
    if all(x == 6 for x in bottom_circles):
        print("Board is full")
        return # skip computer move

    # --- computer ---

    player = 'blue'

    while True:
        choose_stack = random.randint(0, 6)

        if not make_move(player, choose_stack):
            print("Wrong move - full stack")
        else:
            break 

    # TODO: check if computer wins

    #if sum(bottom_circles) == 7*6:
    if all(x == 6 for x in bottom_circles):
        print("Board is full")

# --- main ---

window = tk.Tk()
window.title("Connect 4")

player = 'blue'
bottom_circles = [0]*7

canvases = []
circles = []

for col in range(7):
    canvas = tk.Canvas(window, width=100, height=600, background='gray')
    canvas.grid(row=0, column=col)
    canvas.bind("<Button-1>", lambda event, number=col:on_click(event, number))

    canvases.append(canvas)

    circles_column = []
    for row in range(5, -1, -1):
        circle = canvas.create_oval(0, row*100, 100, (row+1)*100, fill="white")
        circles_column.append(circle)

    circles.append(circles_column)

window.mainloop()
```